# z3 MaxSAT example error

Tags: z3

I'm interested in playing around with the MaxSAT/MaxSMT c example (specifically, maxsat.c) provided on the z3 (Microsoft Research) website. Using Visual Studio 2010, I eventually got the example to compile (using a fresh install of z3 4.0). However, I can't get any of my (SMT 2.0) models to run using them. Further, I cannot get the example posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694072/issues-with-utilizing-z3-for-max-sat) question to work either.

In the first case, my compiled program crashes when it tries to call `Z3_get_smtlib_num_formulas` in `get_hard_constraints` of the file. I don't know why, instead, I get the standard windows 7 "this program has stopped working" popup.

In the second case, it reports `unsupported ;benchmark`.

In order to help me to get this work, I was wondering if
(a) Has anyone had similar issues when compiling this code, and if so, how did you resolve them?
or
(b) How can I debug either compilation of the file (assuming it is correct)? Namely, can someone enumerate the correct libraries (and library versions - e.g., z3 4.0?) to include in the compiler options to get this example working?

In either case, information on the error reported in the second case would also be appreciated: what does it mean exactly? The keyword was not valid? That the SMT input is the wrong version? Or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MaxSAT example has not been updated to SMTLIB 2.0 yet. It uses the function `Z3_parse_smtlib_file` to parse the input, which means that it supports only SMTLIB 1.0 at the moment.

This example is distributed alongside Z3, i.e., you should have received a copy in `Z3-4.0/examples/maxsat/`, which also contains compilation and execution scripts.

Compilation should be straight-forward by running `build.cmd` in a Visual Studio Command Prompt, or `build.sh` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The example was also not working (I did forget to mention this earlier), but I fixed that (some environment variables were not set). Do you know if it's possible to replace that function call with a newer one (and possibly any others that are specific to the old standard) and have it work on SMTLIB 2.0?

Comment: Yes, there is a function for SMT2 as well, it's called Z3_parse_smtlib2_file. The example will require further modification though, because this function returns only a single expression, not a set of assumptions and a set of formulas. So, it's not clear how to distinguish between hard and soft constraints in SMT2 (perhaps this could be done through annotations).